# std::vector elements initializing

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<int> v1(1000);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2(1000);
std::vector<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> v3(1000);
```

How elements of these 3 vectors initialized?

About int, I test it and I saw that all elements become 0. Is this standard? I believed that primitives remain undefined. I create a vector with 300000000 elements, give non-zero values, delete it and recreate it, to avoid OS memory clear for data safety. Elements of recreated vector were 0 too.

What about iterator? Is there a initial value (0) for default constructor or initial value remains undefined? When I check this, iterators point to 0, but this can be OS

When I create a special object to track constructors, I saw that for first object, vector run the default constructor and for all others it run the copy constructor. Is this standard?

Is there a way to completely avoid initialization of elements? Or I must create my own vector? (Oh my God, I always say NOT ANOTHER VECTOR IMPLEMENTATION)
I ask because I use ultra huge sparse matrices with parallel processing, so I cannot use push_back() and of course I don't want useless initialization, when later I will change the value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using this constructor (for `std::vector<>`):

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Which has the following [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/):

> Repetitive sequence constructor: Initializes the vector with its content set to a repetition, `n` times, of copies of `value`.

Since you do not specify the `value` it takes the default-value of the parameter, `T()`, which is `int` in your case, so all elements *will* be 0

Comment: I believe _C++11_ changes this to `n default initialized values` instead of one default initialization followed by a number of copies.

Comment: @Attila See my answer for quotes from C++11.

Comment: Yes C++11 change it to n default constructors. Confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

They are default initialized.

> About int, I test it and I saw that all elements become 0. Is this standard? I believed that primitives remain undefined.

No, an *uninitialized* `int` has an *indeterminate* value.  These are default initialized, i.e.,

```
int i;          // uninitialized, indeterminate value
int k = int();  // default initialized, value == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

In C++11 the specification for the constructor `vector::vector(size_type n)` says that `n` elements are default-inserted. This is being defined as an element initialized by the expression `allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(m, p)` (where `m` is of the allocator type and `p` a pointer to the type stored in the container). For the default allocator this expression is `::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T()` (see `20.6.8.2`). This value-initializes each element.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of a vector are default initialized, which in the case of POD types means zero initialized. There's no way to avoid it with a standard vector.

Comment: They're not default-initialized, they're value-initiialized.

Comment: @ildjarn, I knew I was going to screw that up. I can never keep those initialization styles straight.

Comment: Same screw up on my part.  The semantics of C++ still escape me from time to time, and I use the language every day...